# Log4J : Errors in log4j.xml

Tags: log4j

I am using log4j-1.2.17 jar version ,

While starting the application , i am getting the following errors in console

```
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 38 and column 24
log4j:WARN Attribute "ref" is required and must be specified for element type "appender-ref".
log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 47 and column 12
log4j:WARN The content of element type "root" must match "(param*,(priority|level)?,appender-ref*)".
log4j:ERROR No appender named [] could be found.
```

This is my log4j.xml file after editing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" name="FILE">
        <param value="D:\\Two\\test.log" name="File"/>
        <param value="10" name="MaxBackupIndex"/>
        <param value="200MB" name="MaxFileSize"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param value="%d[%t] %-5p(%F:&lt;%M&gt;:%L)- %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>





 <appender class="com.MyAppender" name="customAppen">
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param value="%d[%t] %-5p(%F:&lt;%M&gt;:%L)- %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>




 <appender class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender" name="asynchapp">
  <param name="Blocking" value="false"/> 
    <appender-ref ref="customAppen"/>

    </appender>


    <root level="INFO">


        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>

        <appender-ref ref="asynchapp"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These seem to stem from the `<appender-ref/>` line that is right under `<root>`. That should be removed as it does not reference any appender, and you should probably move your appender-ref for the "customAppen" appender down into the root tag.

Comment: Also remove the `<level value = "INFO"/>` line.... and add info to the root element, like: `<root level="INFO">`

Comment: I have edited my log4j.xml file as mentioned  , please see the update question , how can i move my appender-ref for the "customAppen" appender down into the root tag. ??

Comment: After editing , my errors have been this now log4j:WARN Continuable parsing error 36 and column 24
log4j:WARN Attribute "level" must be declared for element type "root".
Append has been called

Answer (score 0):

In related to the question for others readers, I also think order matters, so need to keep in this order:

```
renderer*, appender*,(category|logger)*,root?, categoryFactory?
```

an example log4j.xml file would look something like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd"> 

    <!-- I created a renderer for the servlet request object so that it --> 
    <!-- is easy to log info about it.  It's also reusable this way in all 
        servlets. --> 
    <renderer renderedClass="javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" 
        renderingClass="com.firstpac.etools.log.HttpServletRequestRenderer"/> 

    <!-- All output goes to eTools logfile ($TOMCAT_HOME/logs directory) --> 
    <appender name="log" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender"> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
        </layout> 
    </appender> 

    <!-- All output goes to DB for client statistics --> 
    <appender name="clientStats" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender"> 
    </appender> 


    <!-- This is our logger for the fpcServlets application. It logs all --> 
    <!-- info to files (error/debug...) --> 
    <logger name="com.firstpac.etools.log4j.log"> 
        <level value="debug" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="log" /> 
    </logger> 

    <!-- This is our logger for the fpcServlets application. It logs all --> 
    <!-- statistics info for the user --> 
    <logger name="com.firstpac.etools.log4j.clientStats"> 
        <level value="info" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="clientStats" /> 
    </logger> 

</log4j:configuration>
```

<sub>[Source Appache Logging forums](http://apache-logging.6191.n7.nabble.com/Parsing-problem-td6592.html)</sub>